# hidesBottomBarWhenPushed makes UITabBar "jump"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with a tabbar and a navbar.

I have a `BaseVC` and a `DetailVC`. I'm pushing `DetailVC` from `BaseVC`. I want the tabbar to be under the pushed VC `DetailVC`. I'm using `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to achieve it. It works great, but for some reason while it's animating the push the tabbar is still visible and just when the animation ends the tabbar is hidden. I want it to be under the pushed VC in the animation too.

My code is:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed  = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
```

And the result (the bug) is this:

[image: Gif]

Anyone has an idea why the tabbar "jumps"? Thank you!

Comment: You need to show some more information about the setup of it all.  For example is the tab bar from a UITabBarController that is the root view or something else?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Yes. I have a VC called `RootViewController` that presents a `UITabBarController` that has tabs with a `UINavigationController` that its rootVC is my content vc (`BaseVC`/`DetailVC`). Do you understand this little complex structure? :)

Comment: How does the RootViewController 'present' the UITabBarController?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth `self.present(self.tabBarViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Is it modal?  What is the modal style?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth It is a modal. The default style

Comment: Hmm I've setup what I think is the same and it's working ok.  Do you have a way to post the project so I can take a look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162923/discussion-between-fs-o6-and-upholder-of-truth).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't at the moment.  I'm off to play football in a bit and I need to get ready.  I will take a look later when I get back.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Sure. Can I have your email address to send you the project? Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry no I don't just give it out at random.  Can you put it up on dropbox?  You can always remove it at a later time then.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth OK, I'll post a Dropbox link in a moment

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ea3q3pqa2h2h6u/iOS%20bug%20project.zip?dl=0

Comment: I have re-created the problem in your app.  If I don't get time before I will check it out when I get back from my football game.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Great! Thank you very much

Comment: It is because you have changed the height of the tab bar in your UITabBarController subclass.  You set the frame in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method using this function `setupTabBarHeight` and that prevents it moving when it is animated as the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called during the animation.  In changing the height of the tab bar using that method you have lost the ability for the system to animate it.

Comment: You want the tab bar hidden when `detailVC` is pushed. Why are not setting `detailVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Any idea how can I fix it and keep the tabbar custom height?

Comment: Offhand I'm not sure.  Personally I wouldn't alter the height of the tab bar as you get problems like this and you lose some screen real estate.  I tried a basic custom animation but that didn't seam to work.  I will think about it for a bit but as I say I'm not sure at the moment.

Comment: @beyowulf It doesn't work...

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I can't keep the default height of the tabbar unfortunately, that's an order from the designer... If you'll have any other idea I'll be really happy to try it. Thank you!!

Comment: You are having a problem we used to have and the design is leading the development.  The two should go together and for good design the designer should know the limitations and best practices of the platform.  In the end what happens if you just can't do something that the designer says.  In a case like that you have to just turn around and say no to the designer.  This might not be the case here and I will see if I can come up with something.  Maybe remind the designer that Apple has user interface guidelines for a reason.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Thank you for the advice! If no solution will be found in the coming days that's what I'll have to do, unfortunately...

Comment: I feel for you in that situation.  In my case it wasn't too bad because I have worked for the company for over 20 years in various roles and the designer had been there less than 5.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth That's not the case for me :). But if there is no solution that's what I'll have to do :)

Comment: Right I have found one way that appears to make it work but I will add it as an answer as it's a bit complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having looked at the project in question I have found one way to make it work:

1. Remove the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` from the `TabBarViewController` so that it is not determining the height of the tab bar anymore and thus not stopping the animation working correctly.
2. Create a new swift file called MyTabBar (or whatever you want) and put this in it:

   ```
   import UIKit

   class MyTabBar: UITabBar {

       var tabBarHeight: CGFloat = 100

       override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
           let superSize = super.sizeThatFits(size)

           return CGSize(width: superSize.width, height: self.tabBarHeight)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a storyboard called TabBarStoryboard (or whatever).  It's not going to be used for anything other then to hold a UITabBarController which you later create.
4. In the storyboard set the class type of the UITabBarController to your class of `TabBarViewController` so it gets the correct class when instantiated.
5. In the storyboard set the class type of the UITabBar that belongs to the UITabBarController to MyTabBar so that it too is the correct class when instantiated.
6. In your RootViewController replace this:

   ```
   fileprivate let tabBarViewController = TabBarViewController()
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   fileprivate lazy var tabBarViewController: TabBarViewController = {
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TabBarStoryboard", bundle: nil)
       return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTabBarController") as! TabBarViewController
   }()
   ```
7. In your TabBarViewController add this to the end of the `viewDidLoad` to set the height of the tab bar:

   ```
       if let tabBar = self.tabBar as? MyTabBar {
           tabBar.tabBarHeight = self.tabBarHeight
       }
   ```

Now if you get all that correct you should have a tab bar the size you want and the animation should work correctly because the height of tab bar is not longer controlled by the viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

I had to use a storyboard to hold the basic UITabBarController because I couldn't find a way to set the class of its UITabBar property otherwise (if anyone knows a way add a comment.

In case this is difficult to follow I have uploaded my version of your project to dropbox and this is the link: [PlayWiz-NewVersion.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnlo1ea104lff0n/PlayWiz-NewVersion.zip?dl=0).  Be careful as it will unzip to the same directory structure so extract it to a different folder than the original otherwise you will lose the original.

That method appears to work correctly for me and I see no reason for there to be any problem but test it thoroughly first.

Comment: Can you just remove the file from Dropbox. I don't want it to be downloadable publicly :). Thanks again!

Comment: Done.  I have removed the file from dropbox and deleted my local copy.  The app is looking good.

Comment: Excellent method... I just wish I didn't need a storyboard to execute it!

Comment: @Sethmr You don't. Just subclass UITabBarController and override the tabBar property getter and return a UITabBar subclass instance.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simpler variation of the above example (cheers by the way)
I pasted everything in viewDidLoad, but you can write it prettier.

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // create the normal buttons (controllers)
        let viewControllers = [UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstButton), UINavigationController(rootViewController: secontButton)]
        self.viewControllers = viewControllers

        // create the middle rounded button
        self.tabBar.addSubview(addItemButton)

        // setup constraints
        addItemButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64).isActive = true
        addItemButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64).isActive = true
        tabBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.addItemButton.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        tabBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.addItemButton.centerYAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    }
extension UITabBar {
    // fix clicking the (+) external to the tabbar bounds
    override open func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if (!self.clipsToBounds && !self.isHidden && self.alpha > 0.0) {
            let subviews = self.subviews.reversed()
            for member in subviews {
                let subPoint = member.convert(point, from: self)
                if let result:UIView = member.hitTest(subPoint, with:event) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }

    // this fixes the "jumping" tabBar when using the "hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true"
    override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let superSize = super.sizeThatFits(size)

        return CGSize(width: superSize.width, height: 85)
    }
}
```

Now, just call hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true and push the desired view controller.

Comment: I'm not sure how you see this as simpler than subclass `UITabBar` and overriding sizeThatFits.