# hidesBottomBarWhenPushed is being delayed for the first time

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am pushing viewControllers like that:

```
let editProfileViewController = EditProfileViewController()
editProfileViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
navigationController?.pushViewController(editProfileViewController, animated: true)
```

But when any `viewController` is pushed for the first time - tab bar is not hiding, untill push animation is fully completed, it happens only once, after that even controllers that I not pushed before - have normal behaviour.

I have `UITabBarController` subclassed, maybe its something with `backgroundColor`? I tried to set it in `UITabBarController`, but nothing changed.
If i change `animated` to `false`, then everything works properly

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48198123/7707927

The problem was, that I was calculating TabBar height, in 'viewDidLayoutSubviews' of my subclassed 'UITabBarController'